# Add multiple attachments in a pdf using itext pdf stamper

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfstamper

I want to add multiple attachments to a pdf file. 
When I go into the loop it only attaches the last attachment.

sample code

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FILE);

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(realPath+"/Temp/"+sosValues.getCmaId()+".pdf"));

for(SOSCustomerOrderFile cmaOrder:orderList)
{
    PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(stamper.getWriter(), null, cmaOrder.getFileName(), cmaOrder.getFileData());
    /*  stamper.getWriter(), null, "test.txt", "Some test".getBytes());*/
    stamper.addFileAttachment("Attachment", fs);
}
stamper.close();
```

Comment: it seems u're overriding the attachement in every iteration

Comment: I tested that. Apparently, it's OK to do so. I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which iText version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have adapted the existing example [AddEmbeddedFile](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/AddEmbeddedFile) to add more than one attachment, and you claim that only one attachment is added.

I can not reproduce this. I have also adapted the existing example by creating a new example: [AddEmbeddedFiles](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/AddEmbeddedFiles)

```
public static final String[] ATTACHMENTS = {
    "hello", "world", "what", "is", "up"
};
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    for (String s : ATTACHMENTS) {
        PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
            stamper.getWriter(), null, String.format("%s.txt", s),
            String.format("Some test: %s", s).getBytes());
        stamper.addFileAttachment(String.format("Content: %s", s), fs);
    }
    stamper.close();
}
```

The result contains all the expected attachments:

[image]

The only difference that I see, is that you give every embedded file the same name, but even if I do that, I can still see all the attachments correctly.

Another difference, is that I use an array of `String` values, but that shouldn't really matter, assuming that `cmaOrder.getFileName()` indeed returns a file name (e.g. "order1.doc", "order2.xls",...) and that `cmaOrder.getFileData()` returns a `byte[]` with the actual bytes of that file. By not telling us what the `SOSCustomerOrderFile` class is about, you are forcing us to make that assumption.

If you have the file on disk, you could also do something like this:

```
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
    stamper.getWriter(), cmaOrder.getFilePath(), cmaOrder.getFileName(), null);
```

That is: if the `SOSCustomerOrderFile` class has a `getFilePath()` method that returns the path to the file. We don't know that, we don't have access (nor do we want access) to your complete code base. We can only create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) in order to try to reproduce the problem, and our SSCCE tells us that your allegation is wrong. You can prove that you're right by adapting our SSCCE in such a way that we can run it on our machines and reproduce the problem.

Comment: so i need to store the file names in an array.
these attachments are not just txt files, they can be doc or odt files too.

Comment: @iampitre Did you try my standalone example? Does it work? If not, then maybe you're using an old iText version. If it does, then there's maybe something wrong with the `SOSCustomerOrderFile` we don't know anything about.

Comment: SOSCustomerOrderFile is a class , linked to the database, having attachment files.
and orderList is the total number of files present for that perticular SOSCustomerOrder.

Comment: May be i should us the latest version of itextpdf

Comment: So my assumption was right, `getFileName()` returns a simple `String` with a file name whereas `getFileData()` returns the bytes of the file. In that case, the SSCCE I wrote, reflects the actual situation.