# Add attachment using iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm having a little bit trouble changing from PdfStamper.AddFileAttachment that receives four arguments to PdfStamper.AddFileAttachment which recieves PdfFileSpecification object as an argument. The thing is i want to add files to my pdf document as an embedded files,
Can some one tell me if i'm doing this the right way?!

I've replaced the : `iText_Stamper.AddFileAttachment(desc, b, s, s);`

with:

```
PdfFileSpecification pfs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(iText_Stamper.Writer,
                            f.sDataFileName, s, b);
                        pfs.AddDescription(desc, true);
                        iText_Stamper.AddFileAttachment(desc, pfs);

                        PdfTargetDictionary target = new PdfTargetDictionary(true);
                        target.EmbeddedFileName = s;
                        PdfDestination dest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
                        dest.AddFirst(new PdfString(desc));
                        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAction action = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfAction.GotoEmbedded(null, target,
                            dest, true);
                        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(desc);
                        chunk.SetAction(action);
                        iText_Stamper.Writer.Add(chunk);
```

Is this sufficient? am i doing it right?
I'll be glad for some help.

Comment: What makes you suspect you are doing something wrong? What is different from your expectations?

Comment: i followed this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687631/attaching-files-to-a-pdf) for a proper solution. looks fine but my document is of a type:  **Winnovative.PdfCreator.Document**
and there is no method which accepts chunk type, though i cannot finish.

Comment: *my document is of a type: `Winnovative.PdfCreator.Document`* - so you are using a `Document` from a different pdf library and wonder why it behaves differently?

Comment: threw PdfStamper there is a way to get the writer and add the chunk to it.
but still it doesn't work.

Comment: *to get the writer and add the chunk to it.* - what chunk do you mean? I don't see anything in your question that indicates that you want to add done chunk.

Comment: I've updated the code sample.

Comment: Ah, Now the problem becomes clearer. No, you cannot simply add chunks to the writer underlying the stamper like that. I'll give more details later, currently I'm on a smart phone only.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is that you assume that the `PdfWriter` descendant `iText_Stamper.Writer` can be used like a `Document` to which you can add text chunks using the `Add` method, and expect iTextSharp to layout such material automatically.

The class hierarchy unfortunately suggests this as both `PdfWriter` and `Document` implement the interface `IElementListener` which provides a method `bool Add(IElement element)`.

Nonetheless, *this assumption is wrong*, the class hierarchies overlap for internal code reuse reasons, not to suggest similar usages; the `Add` implementation of the `PdfWriter` descendant `iText_Stamper.Writer` merely returns `false` and does not even attempt to add the given element to the document.

In particular in case of pages the stamper retrieved from the underlying `PdfReader` (and didn't add to them) this does make sense: If there is content somehow scattered across a page, where should the stamper add the new content? Should it consider the existing content background material and start at the top? Or should it somehow find a big unused page area and paint the elements there? (In case of newly added pages, though, the stamper indeed could have been programmed to serve like a regular `PdfWriter` and have allowed linkage with a `Document` to automatically layout content...)

Thus, to allow for new content to be automatically layout'ed, you have to tell iTextSharp where to put the content. You can do this by means of a `ColumnText` instance like this:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(result, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
{
    PdfFileSpecification pfs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(stamper.Writer, pdfPath, pdfName, pdfBytes);
    pfs.AddDescription(pdfDesc, true);
    stamper.AddFileAttachment(pdfDesc, pfs);

    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(30, 30, reader.GetPageSize(1).GetRight(30), 60);

    PdfTargetDictionary target = new PdfTargetDictionary(true);
    target.EmbeddedFileName = pdfDesc;
    PdfDestination dest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT);
    dest.AddFirst(new PdfNumber(1));
    PdfAction action = PdfAction.GotoEmbedded(null, target, dest, true);

    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(pdfDesc);
    chunk.SetAction(action);
    ct.AddElement(chunk);
    ct.Go();
}
```

(I used somewhat more descriptive names than your `f.sDataFileName, s, b`)

In the course of layout'ing your chunks, `ColumnText` also establishes the desired goto-emebedded links.

---

By the way, from your writing *embedded files* and using a `PdfAction.GotoEmbedded` I assumed you attach another PDF. If that assumption happens to be wrong, you might want to use `PdfAnnotation.CreateFileAttachment` instead

Comment: at last i had used only
 
`PdfFileSpecification pfs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(iText_Stamper.Writer,
                                    f.sDataFileName, s, b);
                                pfs.AddDescription(desc, true);
                                iText_Stamper.AddFileAttachment(desc, pfs);`
and that worked.
found at 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823189/add-multiple-attachments-in-a-pdf-using-itext-pdf-stamper]

Comment: *and that worked* - your mentioning chunks made me think you also wanted to be able to open the pdf from the page *content*. If that is not required, that shorter code piece indeed will suffice.